# Automatically detect building intervals and roads from binary 2D digital surface data

Tags: python, opencv, openstreetmap, arcgis

Is there any smooth way to extract building intervals and roads from an image like this?  Red lines was manually drawn. I've tried using OpenStreetMap to do the same thing, but it cannot give data for building intervals.

Thanks!

[Building geometry and building intervals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ4zc.jpg)

Comment: it would be helpful to see (1) the unaltered source data (2) data with annotations. from just the houses, I wouldn't be able to say with certainty where roads are supposed to go. you placed roads between houses that are very close together.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.